# Rounded corners to UILabel in NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a variable text that has a background color and rounded corners. So I'm using UILabel with NSMutableAttributedString.

```
    myAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"hello")
    myAttributedString.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: myAttributedString.length))
    myLabel.attributedText = myAttributedString
    myLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    myLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    myLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Im getting a label with rounded corners only on one side. What should I do to get rounded corners on all sides ?

[image]

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768686/convert-a-string-to-nsattributedstring-in-a-specific-manner

Comment: @karthikeyan I have alreasy added cornerRadius and masktoBounds, tried adding sizeToFit too...but I am getting thesame result,

Comment: problem is some where else , are you using uibeizerpath for your label

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik nope

Comment: no problem not in this line

Comment: try same code without setting attributed string

Comment: @karthikeyan that works...but i have variable text and background, thats why im using attributed string

Comment: are you seen this `UIColor.red` ,but it is not affect in anywhere

Comment: better have u attach  ur project'

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik This label is in a tableviewcell and i have given constraints from top bottom and leading and trailing. Didnt use bezier path at all

Comment: where are setting corner radius?

Comment: @Sneha - most likely, your constraints are incorrect and the label is extending past the right side of the content view. Try explicitly making your label narrow, so you will see additional empty space at the side of your cell, and see what happens.

Comment: replace all code into layoutsubviews,in cell file and check once

Answer (score 1):

**just increase the width of UILabel (myLabel)**

```
let myAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"hello")
        myAttributedString.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: myAttributedString.length))
        myLabel.attributedText = myAttributedString
        myLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        myLabel.clipsToBounds = true
        myLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true

// your code is right
// just increase the width of UILabel (myLabel)
```

Comment: I canot set a fixed width to my label as the content will change anytime.